# Icon -- how to implement equivalent of ZipWith

Tags: lazy-evaluation, icon-language

In Icon, every expression is basically a stream. Most of the functions like `*` are named in a way that's suggestive of what they do to a single element.

For instance, here is `foo.icn` which maps `* 2` over a stream.

```
procedure main()
    every write((1 | 2 | 3) * 2)
end
```

I couldn't tell from the small bits of Icon documentation I've seen how it would interleave two non-trivial streams ... and whether a singleton like `2` is a one-element stream or some kind of magical scalar value that distributes and sometimes behaves as an infinite stream ... similar to how scalar extension works in APL.

Doing a test with two non-trivial streams shows what traversal order Icon uses. The rightmost stream is the innermost loop and streams can be traversed multiple times.

This is also nice because it means that we don't need a distinction between a scalar and a singleton stream.

```
procedure main()
    every write((1 | 2 | 3) * (2 | 0 | 0))
end
```

produces

```
% icon foo.icn
2
0
0
4
0
0
6
0
0
```

However, I can't figure out how to write an operation that traverses two streams at the same time ... How would you implement the equivalent of `zipWith`?

Here's an example using the hypothetical `zipWith` function, with `*` passed in as a string. (I'm not sure whether Icon has first-class functions)

```
procedure main()
    every write(zipWith("*", (1 | 2 | 3), (2 | 0 | 0)))
end
```

Which would produce:

```
2
0
0
```